# Do body styles from Pokemon have any effect on gameplay?

Tags: pokemon-series

Sites like Bulbapedia and Psypokes list Pokemon by body styles, but nowhere is explained when they were introduced or what their function is.

Are the body styles only a way to categorise species in the Pokedex (for example, you can organise Pokemon based on "shape" in Pokemon X/Y) or is there any more to them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, while Psypokes might not explain it (anywhere I can see with a quick search), Bulbapedia *does*. If you click the words "Body Style" above the body style icon of any given Pokemon entry, it is a link that takes you to the "[List of Pokemon by body style](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_body_style)" page which states:

> This is a list of Pokémon by their body style according to the
>   Pokédex. This listing was added to the search methods in the
>   Generation IV Pokédex. The game only uses symbols to define each group
>   and without any fixed order so the titles below are simply fan-created
>   descriptions.
>
> Pokémon with multiple forms may be listed differently depending on the
>   sprite used in the main Pokédex entry, which can be changed in
>   Generation V and VI. Currently, the only Pokémon who change
>   drastically enough for this to apply to are Giratina and the Forces of
>   Nature.

So, no, body styles have no effect on game-play. They are just a different way of searching through the Pokedex. Useful if you are trying to assemble a themed team with certain visual qualities, or if you can't remember the name of a pokemon, but know vaguely what it looks like.